# find all the polynomials that have a tangent at the form...

Tags: polynomials

Let m be an integer and observ all the polynomials $p_m(x)=mx^2+mx+m$.
Which of these polynomials have a tangent $y=-x+z$, where z is an integer too. 
(you may not use derivation!)

I figured out that it is true for $m=1$ and $m=-1$. Are there more? And how can I show it without derivation.

Comment: By "without derivation" do you mean the difficult geometric and algebraic methods that were used for polynomials before calculus was discovered/invented? Are limits allowed in the answer?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I am not sure about the limits.

Comment: @NickPodowalski Can you calculate the derivative using limits. Is it allowed...?

Comment: Of course I can, and that was the way I found the results $z=1$ and $z=−1$. But I don't think that is allowed. Are there other options?

Comment: Did you get anything from the answer below?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $y=-x+z$ is a tangent line.  Then, the polynomial $p_m(x)$ just touches the line $y=-x+z$.  So let's substitute the line into the polynomial.

$$
-x+z=mx^2+mx+m
$$

By rearranging,

$$
0=mx^2+(m+1)x+(m-z).
$$

For the curve to just touch the line, it must be that this polynomial has a double root.  Having a double root is the same as the discriminant vanishing, so you're looking for solutions to

$$
(m+1)^2-4m(m-z)=0.
$$

Solving this for $z$ gives

$$
z=\frac{3m^2-2m-1}{4m}.
$$

Now, the question is, when is this an integer?  Since $m$ must divide the numerator, $m$ must divide $-1$, so $m=\pm 1$.  When plugging in $1$ for $m$, you get $z=0$ and when you plug $-1$ in for $m$, you get $z=-1$.

Comment: I'm not getting the $z=1$ case from the OP, so there might be an error somewhere ...

Comment: My wrong. Of course I mean $m=1$ and $m=−1$. I didn't get the point about the sentence “Since m must divide the numerator, m must divide −1, so m=±1.“ Can you explain it in other words?

Comment: You need $z$ to be an integer, so the denominator must divide the numerator evenly.  Since $m$ divides the denominator, it must divide the numerator.  In the numerator, since $3m^2-2m$ is already divisible by $m$, that just leaves the $-1$ to be divisible by $m$.  If this doesn't work, I can try to think up another approach.

Comment: That is enough. Thanks a lot.